# Hidden scrollbars do not allow page scrolling. (CSS)

Tags: css, scrollbar

After using the code:

```
body{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

The scrollbar disappears from the right-hand side of the page but as a consequence, I can no longer scroll up or down the page unless I click the scroll wheel on the mouse and drag in the direction I wish to scroll. Any ideas on how to combat this?

Comment: change it to `overflow-x:hidden;`

Comment: It shouldn't prevent you from scrolling the entire page .. can you show us an example?

Comment: @ExplosionPills Yes it will block him because it won't render anything past the bottom or side of the page therefore there is nothing to scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the purpose of `overflow: hidden;` is not to hide the scroll bars - that is a consequence of what is really happening, that is - all the content that exceeds the "visible" area is clipped (hidden).

You are basically looking for something (hiding scrollbars) that is *not* the purpose of `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: Right. Overflow acts on content that overflows the width or height of its container. Nothing to do with scroll bars, although, it does affect them.

Comment: that's correct - scroll bars can be seen as a *consequence* of standard `overflow` behaviour!